# Spanish law and IP address as evidence

Tags: criminal-law, internet, spain

I have more or less  a sense of what the answer is, but I'd rather explore some sides of the question I might not be aware of.

In short, a friend of mine (Spanish, living in Spain) has been contacted by an ex-employer (Spanish, established in Spain) which pretends to have conducted an "investigation" indicating that they linked the IP address of the computer my friend used to work on (which was given by the enterprise, and which he would use some times from remote work days) in a fraudulent transaction. They want him to reimburse the money or they'll press charges in the soonest.

Being myself a software engineer, I quite could not see how IP equates identity, so I told him to wave it off, however, what's the potential of such legal tribulations?

The worst that can happen, in my opinion, is for the IP address to serve as a thread to collect proper evidence, such evidence should be materializing and establish a clear link between the IP address and the computer, the computer and the user, and the user and an established crime. Am I off?

Would this even land on a court? Would the police even open a case?

What sort of evidence needs to corroborate the IP to lead to a court considering the case?

In case of the ex-employer pressing charges, what type of compensation could my friend target, since this will be a weight on his reputation and is already starting to be both exactly that and a psychological weight.

Sorry if the questions are a bit abstract, we have no data so far, he just got a call from an intermediary sent by the ex-employer asking my friend to give the money back or else. No further details are available.

Thanks.

Comment: It is evidence, obviously, but it is not proof. They'd have to show how their investigation was conducted, whether they actually have the right IP address, and that nobody else could have done that transaction. For example someone at the company's IT department, who would obviously not use his own IP address.

Comment: @gnasher729 thanks, is IP commonly used by some people to "intimidate" others into believing they can establish a case against them? How frequent is IP used in criminal cases? Could you fight back on premise of false accusations?

Comment: Your friend would first decide whether he committed a fraudulent transaction or not. It's much more risky if you actually did what you were accused of. If he didn't do anything fraudulent, then there _must_ be something wrong with their evidence. If they have good reasons to accuse your friend, then this won't be malicious false accusations. Say they swapped two digits in the IP address. Your friend might tell them which might lead to the right person being caught.

Comment: That's fair, except he did not do it or so he adamantly says. Unrelated to the subject, he's being - apparently - the subject of a reputation attack, whether any evidence is going to be provided by the ex-employer or not, regardless of its merits after the examination of the police or court, a lot of people are getting aware of the affair and might stop working with my friend who managed to take some clients with him when he left (he was not subject to any non-compet agreement) or rather the clients went with him more so.
At any rate, point taken, thanks for the reply and time!